# Ruby safe operator for the last element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to check if resource[:contractor] (resource is a hash) includes bank_transfer.creaditor_name (which is string) like below:

```
resource['contractor'].include?(bank_transfer.creditor_name)
```

I need to cover case when `bank_transfer.creditor_name = nil` - how to do that using ruby safe operator ? With current implementation I'm getting an error:

```
 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

From the business perspective I cannot just do:

```
bank_transfer.creditor_name&.include?(resource['contractor'])
```

Comment: Is `resource['contractor'].include?(bank_transfer.creditor_name.to_s)` too cute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just check for `nil` upfront?

```
bank_transfer.creditor_name && 
  resource['contractor'].include?(bank_transfer.creditor_name)
```